# flutter dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() returns null

Tags: flutter, state, demo, inherited-widget

I am trying to use InheritedWidget approach to share state down the Widget tree. For this, I am making a simple counter app. You can add, subtract, multiply or divide the counter however you like.

It's a small demo so best practices are not followed. The line with code `context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>()` seem to be `null` for some reason. When looking at samples and doc, it should find the MyInheritedWidget in the widget tree and return it. However, I am getting complaints from flutter tool that it is null. And, in deed it is `null` when asserted as well.

What is the reasoning here for failed return here? And, how do I need to do it such that I can receive the instance?

**File: main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Counter(),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  const Counter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterState createState() => CounterState();
}

class CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Counter App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: MyInheritedWidget(
        counterState: this,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
            return CounterViewer(
                counterState: MyInheritedWidget.of(context).counterState);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addCounter(int value) {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  void subtractCounter(int value) {
    setState(() {
      counter--;
    });
  }

  void multiplyCounter(int value) {
    setState(() {
      counter *= value;
    });
  }

  void divideCounter(int value) {
    setState(() {
      counter = (counter / value).toInt();
    });
  }
}

class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final CounterState counterState;

  const MyInheritedWidget(
      {Key? key, required Widget child, required this.counterState})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) {
    final MyInheritedWidget? widget =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>();

    assert(widget != null);
    return widget!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class CounterViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  final CounterState counterState;

  const CounterViewer({Key? key, required this.counterState}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.green.shade200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 180,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              '220',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey.shade50,
                fontSize: 60,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Add'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Subtract'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Multiply'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Divide'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Update: I seem to have passed the wrong context to the `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` method. Changing from `context` to `innerContext` fixed the issue.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Counter App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: MyInheritedWidget(
        counterState: this,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
            return CounterViewer(
                counterState: MyInheritedWidget.of(innerContext).counterState);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```